# Asking for some data sources relating to democratic score of all countries in 2020?

Tags: politics

I am wondering if there are some sources for the democratic level of countries all over the world in 2020? (to separate Democratic and Dictatorship)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[V-dem](https://www.v-dem.net/en/) and [Polity IV](https://www.systemicpeace.org/polityproject.html) probably have the most commonly used measures of democracy/autocracy in political science.